# RESTEasy client works stand-alone but fails within Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, resteasy

I have with me the client interface for a web service that was built using JBoss/RESTeasy. The web service calls work fine when they are invoked from a stand-alone app, but as soon as I put them into a webapp running in a Tomcat container (on the same machine), they start behaving weirdly. Some of the calls return empty results while some others simply fail with this exception:

> org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Error status 404 Not Found returned

Any idea of what might be going on? Could this be a result of a library conflict? All the required client libraries are in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the webapp.

Comment: See [404 response on simple RESTeasy example with Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18091525/2390083)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your services are not deployed properly. Take a look at your catalina.out or some other logs for more details.