# 404 response on simple RESTeasy example with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, resteasy

I am trying to put together a very simple "hello world" service with Tomcat and RESTeasy. But when I try to test it, all I get are 404 responses from Tomcat. Here are the steps I followed, hopefully someone can point out where I went wrong:

1. Created a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. The Target Runtime is set for Apache Tomcat 7.0, Dynamic web module version 3.0.
2. Copied all of the jar files from resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA-all.zip into WEB-INF\lib
3. Added one class:

```java
    package com.eshayne.resteasy;

    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/sampleservice")
    public class SampleService {
        @GET
        @Path("/hello")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        public String hello()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

1. Set `web.xml` to:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
        <display-name>resteasy</display-name>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/restful-services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/restful-services</param-value>
        </context-param>
    </web-app>
```

1. Added the new project to Tomcat and restarted Tomcat (within Eclipse)
2. Opened a web browser and requested /resteasy/restful-services/sampleservice/hello

This returns a 404 response from Tomcat with the description:

> The requested resource (/resteasy/restful-services/sampleservice/hello) is not available.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the URL for a given resource is not in fact `<display-name>/<servlet-mapping>/<class Path>/<method Path>`. It is actually `<project-name>/<servlet-mapping>/<class Path>/<method Path>`.

Comment: That helped me out. Anyway, I have posted an answer with the correct "wording".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried visiting variations on the URL - e.g.  /restful-services/sampleservice/hello

Comment: Yes - although my understanding is that the URL should be the concatenation of the display-name, servlet-mapping, class Path and method Path. Still, just to check I've tried the variation you suggested as well as every other combination I could think of, all with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from [RESTEasy tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial/page-2): The URL to access a resource consists of

```
<web context>/<class level @Path>/<Method level @Path>
```

For example, if you deploy `demo.war`, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/sampleservice/hello
```

And there must be a `servlet-mapping` in `web.xml`, for example:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sampleservice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```